# Как шифровать url картинки?

Tags: безопасность, html, защита, img

День добрый!
 Есть у меня один вопрос, ну, не так уж важное, но в целях безопасности думаю стоит решить эту проблему.
Так, у  меня в страничке есть банальные "картинки", можно сказать, в виде:

```
<img src="путь_к_изображению" />
```

Вот, теперь скажите пожалуйста, как можно шифровать путь картинки? Чтобы там было всякие крякозябры при просмотре html кода в браузере, но картинки отображались правильно.

Просто у меня в путях очень важные информации идут, из-за этого необходимо скрыть от посторонних глаз.

**UPD:**

url картинки в таком виде:

```
<img src="http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:80/videstream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin&pri=3&ratio=1" />
```

Это онлайн трансляция ip камеры.
Очень хочется скрыть пароль, адрес, юзера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Динамическое зеркало

**Описание:**

Предположим что есть чудесные страницы на удалённых хостах и мы хотим внести их в наше пространство имен(сайт). Для FTP серверов мы бы использовали программу зеркало которая в действительности управляет обновлениями копий удалённых данных на локальной машине. Для веб-сервера мы могли бы использовать программу webcopy которая делает похожие вещи по HTTP. Однако обе эти технологии имеют один главный недостток: локальная копия актуальна всегда настолько, насколько часто мы запускаем эту программу. Было бы намного лучше если бы зеркало было не статическим должно быть полное соответствие копий, вне зависимости от частоты запуска этой программы. Вместо этого мы хотим динамическое зеркало с автоматическим обновлением данных когда это необходимо (обновление данных на удаленном сервере).

**Решение:**

Для обеспечения этой функции мы отобразим удаленную страницу или даже полностью удаленный сайт в наше веб-пространство используя Proxy Throughput опцию ( флаг [P]):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~quux/
RewriteRule ^hotsheet/(.*)$ http://www.tstimpreso.com/hotsheet/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~quux/
RewriteRule ^usa-news\.html$ http://www.quux-corp.com/news/index.html [P]
```

Answer (score 4):

Если есть доступ к настройке web-сервера, то самым правильным решением было бы забросить картинки в отдельную папку и создать алиас, перенаправляющий туда все запросы на получение изображений.
Например, для Apache это можно сделать так ( [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) ):

```
AliasMatch ^/image/(.*)$ /my/hidden/privat/path/image/$1
```

или так

```
AliasMatch ^/(.*)\.jpg$ /my/hidden/privat/path/image/$1.jpg
```

Если такой способ не подходит, то можно проиндексировать картинки и написать скрипт, возвращающий изображение по его индексу ([php GD](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php) в помощь), но ИМХО это изврат.

И третий способ - вставлять в код страницы не ссылку на изображение, а уже сами данные:
[Внедрение картинки (данных) непосредственно в HTML-код](http://houseofhorse.ru/?/articles/base64.html).

Answer (score 3):

Даже если вы сделаете кракозябры, люди нажмут сохранить веб страницу как файл и все картинку будут сохранены... и какая разница будет откуда они были скачаны?

Answer (score 1):

Даже если вы зашифруете путь, в дебаггере пути отследить можно будет. 
Попробуйте поиграться с mod_rewrite, если у вас apache.

[Подборка примеров](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/rewriteguide/)

Comment: если .htaccess пропишу пароль,юзера сработает ли реврайт ? Попробовал,

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^.*/imgcam/1$ http://хх.ххх.х.хх:80/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin&pri=3&rate=1 [L,R=301]

пока не работает.

Comment: сработает...
то, что у вас написано -- это физическое перенаправление...  
почитайте очень полезный сайт [htaccess.net.ru](http://htaccess.net.ru/), там много примеров

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался, помог мне [html obfuscator](http://htmlobfuscator.com/)

Comment: Как бы это не решение и служит только для того, чтобы школьники не пролезли.

Comment: @lampa, на что Вы намекаете ? )))

Comment: Ну первое это то, что прямую ссылку я спокойно увижу через отладчик браузера. Ну а второе - это всё вытекающее из первого.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал замуровать данное дело во флеш. На чуточку надежней.

Comment: У меня просто поток с камер считывается через тэг img. И там же в виде параметров передается логины-пароли,что не хорошо. Скажите, если знаете,как то можно скрыть это ?(Насчет отладчика я завтра проверю, показывает или нет пути к камерам и логины)

Comment: @lampa, ну блин, видно все через дебаггер... Что еще можно сделать ?

Comment: > И там же в виде параметров передается логины-пароли

А разве не очевидно, что нужно не URL шифровать, а принципиально другой путь искать? Паролям в URL не место, и пока они там есть - что-то другое менять смысла нет, от слова "совсем".

Comment: Как вариант, который имеет место быть: обфусцированный флеш, который будет получать картинку, переводить в base64 и отдавать его через ExternalInterface javascript'у. Ссылку на картинку можно получить деобфускацией флеша, либо сканом tcp. Другой вариант: поставить мост между клиентом и IP-камерой. Мост принимает картинку и потом раздает её. Но тут уже нужно знать софт. Т.к. у вас с точностью 100% формат картинки mjpeg, то по данному вопросу нужно искать в сторону: mjpeg stream.

Comment: @klopp, как бы мне этого хотелось, но разработчики ip камеры именно так и предлогают использовать лаив стрим видео на сайте :
*http://apexis-us.com/forum/embed-live-stream-on-website-t834.html#p3729*